# Do I need to cleanup after using System.Reflection in an aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.reflection

I have the following method that is called when reloading certain pages in my app. The point being to interrupt the current transaction, ask for authentication and call a specified function when coming back to the page to complete the transaction. State, and the method name are saved in Session in the interim.

After redirecting back to the page, the method executes and everything looks fine, but when clicking on a link to the same page it now just displays the same page, not a new page with empty fields etc. and, no page events fire. Eventually if I leave the page for long enough, maybe 5 minutes, it will refresh the page or clicking a button with a Response.Redirect call will do it.

Call the same page method normally w/o reflection and it looks to be fine. It seems as if using reflection may be keeping the page object in memory and not allowing it to be GCed. What is going on here? There are plenty of workarounds, but I'd still like to understand it for the future.

```
protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoadComplete(e);
    if (IsRestoredPageState && priorPageState.CallingFunction != null)
    {
        var completeAction = this.GetType().GetMethod(priorPageState.CallingFunction);
        completeAction.Invoke(this, null);
        completeAction = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you try to do authentication this way?

Comment: The short answer being code reuse. The MFA is used in multiple pages in the app.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this makes no sense at all. You are calling some method in OnLoadComplete. But after that, of course the mage will follow its normal lifecycle and execute the rest of its processing, as if you hadn't called a method in OnLoadComplete. What is the "MFA" you are referring to? And again, why do you try to handle authorization yourself? What is wrong with the normal ASP.NET mechanism? That seems to be doing far better with respect to code reuse. And it doesn't need this strange hack.

Comment: MFA being multi-factored authentication using a third party service.